# Maven Transitive Dependency Issue with CXF and ACEGI

Tags: maven

I have a pom file which originally had the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId> 
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId> 
    <version>2.5.2</version> 
    <scope>runtime</scope> 
</dependency>
```

According to mvn dependency:tree, the above dependency has the following transitive dependencies:

```
[INFO] \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:2.5.2:runtime
[INFO]    +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-common:jar:2.5.2:runtime
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO]       +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:runtime
[INFO]       +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO]       +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO]       |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO]       |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO]       |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO]       \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:runtime
```

I then add the following dependency to my pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.acegisecurity</groupId>
    <artifactId>acegi-security-cas</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run a mvn package, it erases the spring dependencies from cxf (i.e. - spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar, etc...) and replaces them with the 1.0 versions from the acegi plugin. If I run a dependency:tree, it now says the following:

```
[INFO] \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:2.5.2:runtime
[INFO]    \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-common:jar:2.5.2:runtime
```

How do I force maven to use the newer versions from cxf instead of the older versions from the acegi dependency? I tried adding an exclusion to the acegi dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.acegisecurity</groupId>
    <artifactId>acegi-security-cas</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

However, when I run mvn package, I now get no spring-aop jar (it doesn't include the version needed by cxf or the version included with the acegi security).

I know that I could manually write out each of the transitive dependencies from cxf. However, is there any better approach that I could use to get maven to use the spring dependencies from cxf and not from the old acegi?

Thanks.